# Custom Form Redirects to Post after Submit

Tags: redirect, forms

First things first. I´m no PHP pro, but my boss wants me to do this, so if I made a major mistake, don´t facepalm too hard :)

So I have this custom built form on this site:
http://meilenstein-online.com/

But I can´t test the form, because when I hit submit without filling anything in, it redirects me to the first post, which I then deleted, and now the site is empty after submitting.

When I fill out the form and hit submit, I get a 404.

What I´ve done and tried:

- Homepage is the page you see (which should prevent the redirect)
- I didn´t use "name" in the form
- action is `<?php the_permalink(); ?>`
- used "#" in form action (results in an empty page)
- usedt "" in form action (results in an empty page)

You can find the form here:
http://codepad.org/VIAO9RvD

Please not that I used a tutorial to build the form, since my PHP-Knowledge isn´t good enough, to build a form from scratch all by myself. Unfortunately I can´t post the link to the tutorial, but you see the code in the link above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input name attribute value name is reserved by WordPress, this is the problem i have found after visiting and testing your form, simply replace name="name" with name="fullName" etc.

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['name']); ?>" />
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="fullName" placeholder="Name*" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_POST['fullName']); ?>" />
```

Comment: I was sure I changed that already, but it seems to have sneaked back in >.> After looking at the code for too long, I guess I was just blind to it. Thanks for your answer.